# Loop through all the rows of temp table to set values in another temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, temp-tables

I had a little bit complex scenario to work on. I have a set of stored procedures(one for each search criteria) to search Records based on the search criteria we choose in SQL SERVER. 
For example, if you take one stored procedure it returns a set of columns(records) by taking "firstname" as input parameter to search based on the first-name.

For example, the stored procedure is returning record_id, record_check_id, memberid, memberlname, memberfname, address1, address2, city1, State1, Zip1 and Phone based on some joins. 
The address fields are coming from the table Member_adress table by this condition,  Member_adress.record_id = records.record_id. Now I have to get those address fields from another 
table member_additional_address if record_check_id = 1.

For this I tried in this way.

I'm getting all the records that meets the member first-name field as our input field.

```
select a.record_id, a.record_check_id into #temp_table From   
 members b 
 inner loop join records a 
 on a.member_id = b.member_id
 Where b.fname like @firstname
```

Now, my requirement is to check the  record_check_id of these records in the temp table(#temp_table) and if it is 1(one), 
 we need to return the address fields from the member_additional_address table rather than getting from member_address table. 
 If the one record has @record_check_id = 1 and doesn't have any records in @member_additional_address table with that record_id, then we need to show the details from member_address itself.

To do this, i created a temp table with those address fields,

```
declare @Addressinfo table 
(
address1 varchar(30),
address2 varchar(30),
city varchar(30),
state char(2),
zip char(5))
```

Next:

```
While (Select Count(*) From #temp_table) > 0 
if (record_check_id = 1)
update t
set 
t.address1 = f.address1,
t.address2 = f.address2,
t.city = f.city,
t.state = f.state,
t.zip = f.zip,
t.zip_ext = f.zip_ext
from @Addressinfo t
join @member_additional_address f (nolock)
on t.record_id= f.record_id
where record_check_id = 1
.
.
.
.
.
//something like this
```

And Next looking to return all the desired columns by joining records table with the records of @addressinfo temp_table. 
Please let me know how can i implement the logic here. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Could you post the table structure for `member_address` and `member_additional_address`?

Comment: Both has same columns(structure): Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip.. @FelixPamittan

Answer (score 0):

In general in SQL you want to avoid using loops. Your first query will boil down to:

```
select 
    a.record_id, 
    a.record_check_id 
into #temp_table 
From   
    members b join records a 
    on a.member_id = b.member_id
Where b.fname like @firstname
```

Which will do the same thing in a set based manner.

A quick note on the second part, using nolock is generally frowned upon unless you are happy with its pitfalls. If you're not sure what they are, then don't use it. Using it on a temp table like that probably isn't giving you any benefit in any case. Now, with that said, I would do this, without using the intermediate step of a temp table:

```
select 
    a.record_id, 
    a.record_check_id,
    isnull(f.address1,t.address1),
    isnull(f.address2,t.address2),
    isnull(f.city,t.city),
    --etc--
From members b 
    join records a 
        on a.member_id = b.member_id
    left join @member_additional_address f 
        on t.record_id= f.record_id and a.record_check_id = 1
    left join @Address_info t on a.id = t.id -- I would join on where that address information is coming from 
Where b.fname like @firstname
```

I may have some columns and what not around the wrong way, but I hope this'll help point you in the right direction!

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, but it is not working..  It seems your answer is not using the temp table we created in the first snippet and i need to get the address based on the record_check_id in the records table.. Can you please give some more in-detail solution